# How to read a single integer in a string mixed with numbers and characters?

Tags: java, integer

For example, if I have
`0]+4`

How do I read and eat just the zero?

EDIT: So it looks like I've been really unclear. Let me edit things.
All I want to do is to get the first integer that appears in a string of digits and characters. The first component of the text will ALWAYS be an integer. I can have any combination of this. For example, I can have any of these:
`43SOMETEXT424`  `3blahblahblah64blahblahblah` `5MoreText`

I would return 43, 3, and 5 from reading this text, respectively.

Comment: Integer.parseInt doesn't work, I get a NumberFormatException

Comment: See [this earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381560/parse-multiple-doubles-from-a-string) for doubles... I'm sure you can make it work for integers.

Comment: Is it always like the format you specified?

Comment: As I stated before, the format is not always 0]+4, but the first character is always a string.

Comment: You mean "the first character is always a digit". Do you only want the first character converted, or could there be a sequence of digits at the start of the string. The variety of answers you are getting are a result of lack of clarity in the question... This probably also explains some downvotes.

Comment: Edited my post for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a long shot without knowing the context of what you're doing... but this code would work:

```
Integer.parseInt("0]+4".charAt(0));
```

If you truly want only the '0' just read the value you have into a String and call `Integer.parseInt()` on the first character of the String.

Comment: The format won't always be 0]+4, but the format will always have a number as the first character.

Comment: @user1831442, either answer posted so far will work for you then.  Mine is a little more lightweight than the other, but the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    int n = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse("0]+4").intValue();
```

strange as it may seem there will be no ParseException, this is how NumberFormat / DecimalFormat works

Comment: I saw the javadocs for NumberFormat it says `Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a number`. Will it produce `0` or `4` of `04` or `40` is not specified. Are you sure it just produces 0 as output?

Comment: But it also says "The method may not use the entire text of the given string". Try it

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "0]+4";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {

            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Try this. I think this is what you want...yes?

Answer (score 0):

```
public char getNumber(final String str){
    final String onlyNumbers = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    return (char) (onlyNumbers.length() > 0 ? onlyNumbers.charAt(0) - '0' : -1);
}
```

Consider using regexs. This won't parse negative numbers, but I doubt you would need to find them here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pattern

```
  Pattern pattern;
   pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d");
   String st=jTextField1.getText();
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(st);
system.out.prinl(matcher.group());
```

Comment: I can't seem to get group to work correctly. There is nothing to group, the compiler complains.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in)
    int number=in.nextInt();
}

//put loop for nextInt fun as many time as you want to get the required number
```