# How to print formatted double value to string in java?

Tags: java

I want to create a String from a double value with 10 character for example

```
Double d = 150.23;
```

The output string like this 0000015023+

I have used this code but it is not working:

```
String imponibile = String.format("%10d%n", myDoubleValue);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: how to parse double from regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681242/java-how-to-parse-double-from-regex)

Comment: @Aenadon OP wants to print the number not parse it. Which means the `regex` at the title is quite misleading. I will edit it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to print `150.23` without the period. Formatting is not supposed to achieve that. You have to:

1. transform the `double` number to a `int` number with the desired rounding and print the `int`:

   ```
   int i = (int) Math.round(100.0 * d);
   String.format("%010d", i)
   ```

   Where `"010"` means print at least 10 digits and pad with zero if there are less. The padding char going before the number of digits.
2. print the `double` and remove the period from the string afterwards:

   ```
   String.format("%011.2f", d).replace(".", "")
   ```

   Note how you now have to specify `11` including the period. And you have to specify the number of digits after the period

I don't think there is a way to print the sign after a number with `String.format`. You can easily require to print it at the start which is the normal way to print numbers:

```
String s = String.format("%+010d", i);
```

And if you must you can use `substring` and concatenation to put it at the end:

```
String imponibile = s.substring(1) + s.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `f` instead of `d`:

```
String imponibile = String.format("%010.0f", myDoubleValue*100);
```

> Floating Point - may be applied to Java floating-point types: float,
>   Float, double, Double, and BigDecimal
>   [Class Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dndec)

Comment: I have try to use your code but I have this string as output:
16.50000000 but I want 0000001650

The myDoubleValue = 16.5

Comment: Ok. Got it.
Hope this helps: String.format("%010.0f", myDoubleValue*100);